# why is this trim-space function so complicated/ugly in emacs lisp?

Tags: regular-expressions

I just spent at least 10m writing a `trim-space` function in Emacs lisp:

```el
(defun trim-space (string)
  (let ((regex "\\`[ \n\t\r]*\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\\)[ \n\t\r]*\\'"))
    (string-match regex string)
    (match-string 1 string)))
```

This is after several iterations. There are several gotchas that I ran into:

1. `^` matches beginning of line, not beginning of string. Likewise for `$`. Documentation on this is not easy to find within Emacs.
2. `.` (dot) doesn't match newline
3. `[:space:]` class doesn't include newline????
4. I also don't like that I have to mess with match-data, giving this function side effects

Finally:

```
ELISP> (trim-space "   deb   ian-
mini")
"deb   ian-\nmini"
ELISP>
```

Meanwhile, using Python:

```python
>>> import re; 
>>> re.findall("(?s)^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$", "   deb   ian-\nmini  ")
['deb   ian-\nmini']
>>>
```

which is much simpler and clean and makes much more sense.

Why shouldn't Emacs lisp look more like Python here?

Note: I know about `string-trim` in Emacs 24. Emacs regular expression syntax is still unintuitive and ugly and non-standard.

Comment: What is the `trim-space` function supposed to do? Only remove spaces from the beginning and end of a string?

Comment: yes (I have to write 12 more characters)

Comment: Regarding documentation, see [Syntax of Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) in the elisp manual.

Comment: In Emacs25 can you use the built in string-trim?  Or the trim functions in s.el?

Comment: Did you consider using the package s and use s-trim ? Not bundled with emacs

Comment: Is this really the question: "*Why shouldn't Emacs lisp look more like Python here?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```el
(defun my-chomp (str)
    "Trim leading and trailing whitespace from STR."
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\`[[:space:]\n]*\\|[[:space:]\n]*\\'\\)" "" str))
```

---

Here's a `let` form to quickly test it:

```el
(let ((str "   deb   ian-
mini    "))
  (defun my-chomp (str)
    "Trim leading and trailing whitespace from STR."
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\`[[:space:]\n]*\\|[[:space:]\n]*\\'\\)" "" str))

  (message "%S" str)
  (message "%S" (my-chomp str)))
```

---

[Reference](https://github.com/jrblevin/deft/blob/2dd64ddc798a009e62289d65abfa621735461b7a/deft.el#L823-L825)

Comment: I like this solution. I'm still not a fan of things like [:space:] not including newline (a bug IMO or "space" should be renamed), and of things like having to escape capture group parens or the nonstandard \\`, \\' syntax (although maybe it can be more powerful). I also don't understand why there's not a side-effect free version of string-match / match-string by default

Comment: You could wrap it in the save-match-data macro.

Comment: @erjoalgo I don't understand what you mean by "side-effect". Does `string-match-p` solve the problem? Here's what its doc-string says: "Same as ‘string-match’ **except this function does not change the match data**."

Comment: but that doesn't allow me to retrieve the data later. it just returns tells me whether it's a match or not. ideally, there should be something that returns a match object or something similar

Comment: @KaushalModi Well, `string-match` modifies a *global* variable, namely `match-data`.  That's a side effect, and pretty different from many other regexp libraries which *return* a ADT with match information instead.

Comment: @erjoalgo Well, that's just how Emacs Lisp works.  It's a language with an awful amount of global (sometimes even hidden) state.  I don't know why, but it is what it is.